# GraphQL API unit testing for user sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I need to write a unit test for a user signing in for an app that uses Ruby on Rails and GraphQL API. On Altair, when performing the signIn mutation, I need to set the server URL as an environment variable, then send a POST request for the mutation to work. I'm trying to do the same thing, just in a unit test file. This is my mutation file:

```
module Mutations
  class SignInUser < BaseMutation
    argument :auth, Types::AuthProviderEmailInput, required: false

    field :token, String, null: true
    field :user, Types::UserType, null: true

    def resolve(auth: nil)
      # basic validation
      return unless auth

      user = User.where('uuid=? OR email=?', auth[:user_id], auth[:user_id]).first()

      # ensures we have the correct user
      return unless user && user.is_active
      return unless user.authenticate(auth[:password])

      user.update_attributes(invitation_status: true) if !user.invitation_status

      { user: user, token: AuthToken.token(user) }
    end
  end
end
```

This is my test file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Mutations::SignInUserTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def perform(args = {})
        Mutations::SignInUser.new(object: nil, field: nil, context: {}).resolve(args)
    end

    test 'sign in user' do
        post "serverurl.com"

        user = perform(
            auth: {
                user_id: "example",
                password: "example"
            }
        )

        assert user.persisted?
    end
end
```

The POST request seems to work since it doesn't return any errors, but `user` returns null. I think it's because my POST request and when I actually sign in the user are separate, so the mutation doesn't work. I tried sending a POST request only and `puts response.body` like so:

```
post "serverurl.com"
puts response.body
```

which gives me a message saying `{"errors":[{"message":"No query string was present"}]}`. This makes me think I have to send the mutation along with the POST request in its parameters or something so I've tried using:

```
post "serverurl.com", params: { signInUser: { input: { auth: user_id: "example", password: "example" } } }
```

but that just gives me a bunch of syntax errors for the `} } }` at the end, which I don't know why.
I'm not sure what else to try here, so some help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Your last example "so I tried using" is missing a set of curly braces here: `auth: user_id: "example", password: "example"` it should be `auth: {user_id: "example", password: "example"}`

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you! that was a stupid little mistake. I fixed it and ```assert_response :success``` passed, but ```response.body``` is still this message ```{"errors":[{"message":"No query string was present"}]}```.

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL queries are strings, and their variables are JSON-encoded. Your example:

```
post "serverurl.com", params: { signInUser: { input: { auth: user_id: "example", password: "example" } } }
```

Likely needs to be something more like this:

```rb
query = "
  mutation signInUser($input: AuthProviderEmailInput) {
    signInUser(input: $input) {
      user {
        id
      }
      token
    }
  }
"

variables = {
  input: {
    auth: {
      user_id: "example",
      password: "example"
    }
  }
}.to_json

post "serverurl.com", params: { query: query, variables: variables }
```